# Can I use .then() with firebaseListObservable i.e this.items = query and .then()

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I want to perform a task of scrolling down when all messages has been loaded in this.items
I am using angularfire2

```
items: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;

                this.items = this.af.database.list('/conversations', {
                  query: {
                    orderByChild: 'chatKey',
                    equalTo: prop + '-' + this.userId
                  }
                })
```

I want to use like below but its not working.

```
items: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;

                this.items = this.af.database.list('/conversations', {
                  query: {
                    orderByChild: 'chatKey',
                    equalTo: prop + '-' + this.userId
                  }
                }).then(()=>{
                      this.scrollToBottom();
                    })
```

this.scrollTobottom code is below and working for other places

```
  scrollToBottom(time?) {
    setTimeout((data) => {
      var element = document.getElementById('123');
      element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight - element.clientHeight;
      console.log("element", element);
    }, time ? time : 4000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it's an Observable Object, you must either use

```
this.items = this.af.database.list('/conversations', {
    query: {
        orderByChild: 'chatKey',
        equalTo: prop + '-' + this.userId
    }
}).subscribe(data => {/* do things */}, error => {/* do error things */})
```

Or

```
this.items = this.af.database.list('/conversations', {
    query: {
        orderByChild: 'chatKey',
        equalTo: prop + '-' + this.userId
    }
})
.toPromise()
.then(/* ... */)
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I usually use is like below:

```
this.items = this.af.database.list('/conversations', {
    query: {
        orderByChild: 'chatKey',
        equalTo: prop + '-' + this.userId
    }
})
.first().toPromise()
.then(response => {
  //code here
})
.catch(error => { //error code here });
```

of course , don't forget to import the relevant libs:(in your component\service)

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/first';
import 'rxjs/Rx' ;
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple. Just correct your code to...

```
items: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;

           let thisChatKey = prop + '-' + this.userId;

            this.items = this.af.database.list('/conversations', {
              query: {
                orderByChild: 'chatKey',
                equalTo: thisChatKey 
              }
            }).then(()=>{
                  this.scrollToBottom();
                })
```